# Ajax field default value on edit form

Tags: forms, ajax, nodes

I want ajax dependent fields in one of my node's form so I am altering the form.

here is the code

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      $selected_first = isset($form_state['values']['field_first'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']) ? $form_state['values']['field_first'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']: '0';
    $form['field_first'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => '_first_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'second-field-wrapper',
    );
    $form['field_first'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $selected_first;

    $form['field_second'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#prefix'] = '<div id="second-field-wrapper">';
    $form['field_second'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['field_second'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'] = _get_second_options($selected_first);
}
/**
 * 
*/
function _first_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_second'];
}
/**
 * Ajax callback for second field
 */
function _get_second_options($occ_id) {
  //array which contains some int values
  return $second_options;
}
```

Some more information: `field_first` is select list of type node reference and `field_second` is checkboxes.

> **Issue**: This works fine while creating the node. But when I edit the
>   same node, the second field doesn't show and also values selected for
>   this field while creating the node are also not checked by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/dfv

Comment: Thank you smile for the suggestion, but this is not working out  form me because I have two fields which are dependent on first_field.